# Get daily count of rows for a Time

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

My database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE record 
(
    id         INT,
    status     INT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And I want to create a generic query to get count of record created  after 3 hours of interval in last day

For example, I want to know in last 1 day after 3 hours  how many records are created.

What I have so far: with a little help from stackoverflow I am able to create a query to calculate the count for a single full day.

```
SELECT
    DATE(created_at) AS day, COUNT(1)
FROM
    record
WHERE
    created_at >= current_date - 1
GROUP BY
    DATE(created_at)
```

This is telling me in full day like 24 records are created but I want to get how many are made in interval of 3 hours

Comment: "I want to know in last 1 day after 3 hours how many records are created."  Can you clarify what you mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count for the last three hours of data:

```
select count(*)
from record
where created_at >= now() - interval '3 hour';
```

If you want the last day minus 3 hours, that would be 21 hours:

```
select count(*)
from record
where created_at >= now() - interval '21 hour';
```

EDIT:

You want intervals of 3 hours for the last 24 hours.  The simplest method is probably `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.ts, count(r.created_at)
from generate_series(now() - interval '24 hour', now() - interval '3 hour', interval '3 hour') gs(ts) left join
     record r 
     on r.created_at >= gs.ts and
        r.created_at < gs.ts + interval '3 hour'
group by gs.ts
order by gs.ts;
```

Comment: Sir thanks for answer , But I want to get records created in last 24 hours , with interval of 3 hours , like    how many created in 21 hours ago  then  18 hours ago , then 15 hours ago then 12 hours and then 9 hours ago and 6 and 3 hours ago. this way

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb760/5   I tried this on `sqlfiddle`  its returning 9 intervals instead of 8 . can you kindly check

Comment: @Ninja . . . It was returning the current time as an empty interval.